# Is There a Way to Automate Copying and Pasting Data From Excel to Powerpoint?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to copy and paste certain tables from excel and paste them in a powerpoint presentation as a bitmap picture once a month. It takes 2 to 3 hours when I do it manually. Is there something I can do to automate this process? I tried recording a macro but it didn't work the way I've anticipated. I haven't tried to write a VBA code yet, just wanted to know if it is worth my time. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Present using Excel. Else Google embedded object Microsoft office...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the tables as objects instead that way it will be automatically updated.

You copy the range you need in Excel then when you paste it in PowerPoint you paste special:

[image]

Then paste as link and choose MS Excel Object.

[image]

When you make changes in Excel the changes should happen in PowerPoint too.

Comment: I tried it now and it works quite well. The thing is, I update the presentation from different workbooks every month, but I don't think that this will be a problem, I guess I can work it out somehow. Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: In that case I would have made a workbook where powerpoint gets the data from and a macro in that workbook that gathers the data from other books.

Comment: That's exactly what I am going to do. Thanks again.